# copy integer to buffer if buffer have enough space in C

Tags: c, copy, integer, buffer

I have a function to copy an integer into buffer if the buffer have enough space

```
void copy_int(int val, void *buf, int maxbytes)
{
    if (maxbytes-sizeof(val) >= 0)
        mempcy(buf, (void *) &val, sizeof(val));
}
```

The problem is it always copies the value to the buffer even when maxbytes is too small.
I wonder why that is?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and **mind them**

Answer (score 9):

`sizeof(val)` is an unsigned value. `int` - `unsigned` produces an unsigned value.

Use: `if (maxbytes >= sizeof(val))`

Answer (score 3):

[`sizeof(val)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned.  Therefore, `maxbytes-sizeof(val)` will also be unsigned, and therefore always be `>= 0`.

You should try `maxbytes-(int)sizeof(val)`.